# UC4 Compactibility with PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, uc4

Can some please tell me if UC4 is compactible with PostgreSQL.
Right now ,UC4 works with Oracle ,want to change it for PGSQL.

Could not get any documents with PGSQL standards for UC4
is UC4 feasible like MSSQL ,Oracle ?

Please help

Comment: Not sure what "compactibility" is supposed to be. Do you mean "compatibility"?

Comment: You could ask the supplier, you paid them for support.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: "compactibility"--> does UC4 support Postgresql was my question.I could see documents stating UC4 supports MSSQL ,Oracle.

Comment: From here [UC4](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/uc4-084231.html) I would say no, this is an Oracle specific application.